# Indy client supports ssl ev?

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, indy10

Indy supports ssl ev?

If it supports what would be the most correct configuration for this ssl?

sslvSSLv2, sslvSSLv23, sslvSSLv3, sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2 ?

I need to use it with IdHTTP.

Comment: What is "ssl ev"? Please clarify your question.

Comment: SSL EV is an "Extended Validation Certificate", apparently it's different from the common ssl.My question is, does programming have any difference? Indy supports this type of ssl? About SSL EV: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate

Comment: SSLEV certificates are just standard certificates that have been signed by the CA of a verified SSLEV provider, the certificate asserts an SSLEV policy OID from that CA, and the certificate has an SSLEV-formatted DN. From OpenSSL's perspective, there should be no difference in using/validating an EV certificate than any other certificate. You can use Indy's `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnVerifyPeer` event of you want to validate an HTTPS server's certificate for this extra criteria.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indy is a phenomenal, cross and stable component. This topic will help many people like me who have worked with Indy but have never used it with SSL. And this issue of SSL EV is something new as well, I just managed to clarify here that it works the same way as other SSL technically speaking, so thank you. If you search for keywords like Indy and SSL EV will only find this topic practically, then I would like to ask if you would not be able to post an example of how to use this kind of certificate with this event. Thank you very much.